# What does "Baba" (बाबा) in the "Baba Nam Kevalam" mantra mean?

Tags: name

Many sources translate "Baba" as "beloved". For instance, [Yogapedia said](https://www.yogapedia.com/definition/6888/baba-nam-kevalam)

> This mantra is used for practice of kirtan in Ananda Marga
>
> Baba means "beloved," nam means "name" and kevalam means "only." Therefore, the mantra may be translated as "only the name of the beloved."

However, [other sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baba_(honorific)) claim that "Baba" (or "[Babaji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babaji)") is a honorific that means "Father". I haven't found any "beloved" translation variant out of the context of Ananda Marga.

Can "Baba" really be translated as "beloved"?